# How open modal programatically from VUE method

Tags: bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I have component with modal

```
<template>
<div class="modal fade" ref="hujek" id="modalChangesSaved" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalChangesSavedLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-dark">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-white" id="modalChangesSavedLabel">{{ title }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{{ message }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger-soft my-0" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['preset'],
    data() {
        return {
            title: this.preset.title ? this.preset.title : 'Informacja',
            message:  this.preset.title ? this.preset.title : 'Zmiany zostały zapisane.',
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

It is easy and if i put code to html with button, modal is open without any problems

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success-soft mb-0" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalChangesSaved">OPEN</a>
<modal-changes-saved :preset="{{ json_encode([]) }}"></modal-changes-saved>
```

but i have another component in vue like update profile, and after update profile i would like show modal message, changes saved. How can i show modal in my another vue component ?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card bg-transparent border rounded-3">
            <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-0" @click="updateProfile">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['user'],
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateProfile() {
            // what code should be here ?
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't this useful in your case? https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#using-thisbvmodalshow-and-thisbvmodalhide-instance-methods

Comment: aaa i dont have BV i need to install. I  am using plain Bootstrap

Comment: Oh yeah, if you want to interactivity, you'll need to get BV here.